# Construct an extension of $\mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}})$ by radicals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rational numbers. Suppose
$$ \mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}}) \leq R \leq \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$$
where $R=\mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}},a,b)$, where $a^{n} \in \mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}})$ and $b^{m} \in \mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}},a)$ for positive integers $m,n$.

Is it possible to construct a field $K$ such that:

1. $R \leq K \leq \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$
2. $K$ is a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}})$
3. $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}})$ by radicals
4. $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}}))$ is solvable ?

How can I construct $K$? I tried to adjoin the $n, m$th roots of unity, but I cannot solve this. Thank You.

Comment: What is the role played by the field $E$? It is somewhat narrowly constrained by $R$, but seems to play no role in your actual goal? Can we use $E=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of3)$?

Comment: I think the question would benefit from a bit more context and/or a description of its origin, and your thoughts. Consult [the abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619) for pointers and suggestions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes. We can use E= $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$. Sorry for that. And other parts of this problem is maybe right.  I guess the field $K$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}, a, b, \xi_{3}, \xi_{m}, \xi_{n})$ where $\xi_{3}, \xi_{m}$ and $\xi_{n}$ are the 3th, nth, mth roots of unity. But i cannot prove that it is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$.

Comment: One of the easiest to prove some extension is Galois is to show that the extension field is the splitting field of some polynomial. Disregarding the inseparable cases, because that does not come to the fore here.